# Run MATLAB program with Web Server inputs

Tags: api, matlab, server

I have a MATLAB application that I want to execute on a linux box with inputs from a web server. Requests to the server would all be from the local network.

Searching for different solutions, I've seen recommendations to host a Django server that serves an HTML form where users could input all the various data needed by the application. When a user fills out the form and submits it, the data would be sent through an API to the MATLAB application, which would serve up the report in a network shared drive.

Would this work well? Is there a different/easier solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more details to know if this would "work well". But in terms of the general outline you presented, seems feasible.

When you say "the data would be sent through an API to the MATLAB application", what exactly do you mean here? What API are we talking about? And what is "the Matlab application"? Do you mean just installing regular Matlab on this server machine, and then having the Django or other web application server run the `matlab` command to run a Matlab program, running as a distinct process (corresponding to a single `matlab -batch` execution, probably?) that services that? Two issues here: One, Matlab is a large program with a slow startup time. Matlab Production Server and similar solutions handle this by maintaining a pool of already-running "warmed up" Matlab worker processes to service incoming requests. Two, licensing: the "regular" Matlab licenses are aimed towards interactive use by humans; running Matlab like that on the server side to handle requests for a web app used by multiple humans may not be covered. Talk to your organization's lawyer or IT licensing expert before doing this.

@Will is right here: The Matlab Production Server is the product or "solution" that MathWorks provides for this scenario. And it's relatively easy to use. But ain't cheap. (On the other hand, when you're talking about Matlab, what is?)

If you have someone who can do a bit of system programming for you, there's a more affordable alternative: use the Matlab Compiler to build your Matlab code into a "CTF" DLL, and write a thin custom server wrapper on top of that, which can accept service calls for the particular Matlab things you need done, and dispatches them to your code. (Running that in a pool of multiple processes, if you want to be able to service multiple concurrent clients.) "Compiled" Matlab libraries that run against the Matlab Runtime do not require any additional licenses for their runtime execution.

Big questions here are: Do you want this to Go Fast? How many clients are you going to have, and how often are they going to be sending requests? What kind of data will be contained in the inputs and outputs to this Matlab code?

Have a look at the `-batch` option to the `matlab` command. Have a look at the various deployment options supported by the Matlab Compiler. And talk to your organization's lawyer.

If you decide to go the `matlab -batch` route, you probably do not want to pass the inputs to your Matlab code as command-line arguments. Command lines and environment variables only pass simple strings, and parsing those sucks, especially once you get in to nontrivial numerics. Bundle up all your inputs as JSON files, MAT files, or something similar, and then pass just a reference to those files (or SQL blobs, or similar) on the command line.

Also, depending on what your Matlab code is like, GNU Octave (https://gnu.org/software/octave/index) may be an option for you. Octave is many years behind Matlab in terms of functionality and stability, and doesn't have equivalents of all the Matlab Toolboxes, so it isn't a drop-in replacement in general terms. But for simple stuff, it works. And it is unencumbered by licensing, and has faster startup times in command-line mode.

Comment: Wow thank you for the in-depth response.

Since I wrote that initial question, I did some more searching and came across the potential solution of using Matlab compiler and using the server to call the executable with the parameters given by clients.

My follow up question is, what languages/frameworks should I use for the custom server wrapper? I have initially been considering an Apache server that would use command-line arguments. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: My pleasure! This is one of the things I do at work, and I'm happy to talk about it. As far as picking a "host" language for your "compiled" Matlab code (MathWorks calls this "deployed" Matlab code): Pick whichever language and framework you and your team know and like, and fits best with the rest of your system. They all work just fine as far as interacting with Matlab goes. And maybe consider nginx instead of Apache as your web server, unless you already have Apache expertise; Apache is powerful but hard to configure.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution (though possibly not the cheapest if your existing MATLAB license doesn't already cover it) is to use [MATLAB Production Server](https://mathworks.com/help/mps/) which basically exists for this category of problem. It has a [RESTful API](https://mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/mps_restfuljson/restful-api.html) that would straightforwardly handle your user input use case.

Comment: Yeah I looked into that. Sadly, my license doesn't include it and the costs are relatively steep.